# Mysql - Select To XML

Tags: mysql, trigger, xml, audit

I'm using a trigger to capture an audit trail. I want to convert the inserted / updated / deleted value to XML and store it in another table.

My trigger look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `MyDB`.`TriggerAudit` AFTER INSERT
    ON `MyDB`.`settings`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_audit_trail (user_uid, table_name, inserted_value) 
    VALUES ('the Username', 'the table name', 'Select to XML In Here')
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In MS SQL Server I can use the FOR XML clause, but I don't know to do this in MySQL. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847674/xml-output-from-mysql).

The answer references [this article](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/mysql-xml.html#TOC_2).

From the answer:

> From the article:
>
> ```
> use strict;
> use DBI;
> use XML::Generator::DBI;
> use XML::Handler::YAWriter;
>
> my $dbh = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:test",
>                        "testuser", "testpass",
>                        { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0});
> my $out = XML::Handler::YAWriter->new (AsFile => "-");
> my $gen = XML::Generator::DBI->new (
>                                Handler => $out,
>                                dbh => $dbh
>                            );
> $gen->execute ("SELECT name, category FROM animal");
> $dbh->disconnect ();
> ```

Comment: Yes, but its not a MySQL Query. any solution to integrate that into triggers or store procedures?

Comment: If you already know the xml schema or can dynamically build it in the procedure, you can use UpdateXML - a description of which is detailed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml).

Comment: If you'd like, I could help with using the function. Could you please provide an example of a desired XML result and source data?